# Closed subscheme of open subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a smooth scheme $Y$, and a closed subscheme $X\subset Y$. If $U\subset X$ is an open subscheme, can we find an open subscheme $V\subset Y$ which contains $U$ as a closed subscheme? I am happy to assume Noetherian/quasi compact assumptions. Everything can be assumed to be over an algebraically closed field of char 0.

Comment: Do you mean "$V$ contains $U$ as a closed subscheme"?

Comment: @Sasha indeed, that is what i meant

Comment: Just take $V = Y \setminus (X \setminus U)$.

Comment: @Sasha you are right, set theoretically this is the natural choice. But what scheme structure do you use here (on the complement of an open subscheme)? I actually need $V$ such that $V\cap X=U$ as a scheme theoretic intersection - your choice a priori satisfies this only set theoretically

Comment: It doesn't matter which scheme structure you use on the closed subscheme, because on the open subscheme there is only one scheme structure compatible with the ambient scheme.